# save and retrieve a class object using coredata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, xcode4

i want to save a uiviewcontroller class in to a coredata and retrieve it from coredata in a button click. i have tried it with nsarchiver and nsunarchiver. converted the class in to a nsdata and save in to coredata. but at the time of retrieving i got an error:

> -[__NSArrayI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d442a0 my code is below

```
// the button press for saving the object

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:viewcontrollerobject];
ViewData *viewdetails=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ViewData" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

viewdetails.view = data;
viewdetails.order = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];


//button press for retrieving the class
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];


NSData *theData;
theData =  [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"view"];

viewcontroller *newviewcontrollerobject; 
newviewcontrollerobject=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];

[newviewcontrollerobject.view setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 300, 150)];
[self.view addSubview:newviewcontrollerobject.view];
```

please help me to correct this code

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

I strongly advise against this application design. You should use Core Data to persist the data of your *Model*, not any *View*, let alone a *Controller*.

Please do read up on **["Cocoa Core Competencies: Model-View-Controller"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)**.

Comment: I perfectly agree with you. +1

Answer (score 0):

This line of code returns you NSArray of NSData objects:

```
[fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"view"];
```

So this will work:

```
NSArray* theDataArray =  [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"view"];
theData =  [theDataArray lastObject];
```